# Penetration testing tool for SharePoint

Tags: security, testing

Does anybody know any good penetration testing tools for SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a web application (in addition to network and client side) penetration testing tool called Core IMPACT that has exploits specifically for Sharepoint. It has been developed and updated by Core Security Technologies.

www.coresecurity.com

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer to similar question here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010general/thread/cfdbf4e7-83d2-43b9-9aaa-6379cbad1cb0

You can also find some more tools here.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few resources on [this blog posting](http://carnal0wnage.attackresearch.com/2012/05/from-low-to-pwned-6-sharepoint.html).  Specifically there's a link to Stach & Liu's page [here](http://www.stachliu.com/resources/tools/sharepoint-hacking-diggity-project/) which has some tools and presentations on sharepoint testing and security.